# EJS replaces quotation marks with &#34;

Tags: express, ejs

I have an express app where I want to send some data along with the page when it's queried. To do this I do the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        let data = "<%= locals.data %>";
</script>
```

And then in express

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    let data = {test: "test"}
    res.render("home.ejs", {data: JSON.stringify(test)});
})
```

Unfortunately, the browser receives the following:

```html
<script>
    let data = "{&#34;test&#34;:&#34;test&#34;}";
</script>
```

I've already tried adding in different `<meta charset="...">` elements, but they didn't end up doing anything.

I know this can be circumvented by just adding in `data = data.replaceAll("&#34;", '"')`, but it feels like there has to be a better way, either to not have to replace the text or to send data to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, `&#34;` is a valid replacement for `"`, but not inside the `<script>` tag. Another problem in your case is that these Javascript quotes appear inside another pair of quotes `let data = "..."`, in which case they would have to be escaped as `\"`. Both are situations that EJS cannot automatically detect.

The following EJS template would work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  let data = JSON.stringify(<%- locals.data %>);
</script>
```

But you must then be sure that `locals.data` has been constructed, as in your case, with `JSON.stringify`, otherwise there is a danger of code injection.

The browser then receives

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  let data = JSON.stringify({"test":"test"});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "<%-" instead of "<%=".

```
console.log(<%-data%>);
```